# Check where a value lies within a sorted list

Tags: python, list

I need to check where a given value lies within a list of intervals.
Let's say I have the following sorted list:

```
    interval = [-5, -2, 0, 10]
```

which represents three sorted intervals (from -5 to -2, from -2 to 0, and so on).

I need to check inside which of these intervals lies a certain value, let's say 1.
The output shloud be something like this:

```
    output = [False, False, True]
```

N.b.: the value I am checking is surely bewteen the minimum and the maximum of the interval list.
I am looking for a smart and compact way, but I have not found anything similar around. Thanks!

Edit: My current solution is the following, but it is quite slow when a very long interval list is used:

```
    value = 1
    interval = [-5, -2, 0, 10]
    output = []
    for num in range (len(interval) - 1):
        if value > interval[num] and value <=interval[num+1]:
            output.append(True)
        else:
            output.append(False)
```

Comment: why not just output the index in the list of your intervals ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html does that for you), then you can always create your `output` list if you really need it in that form.

Comment: Closed intervals, half-open intervals, something else? DId you write code to solve this already (please add)?

Comment: The `bisect` module will quickly find the interval, but it would require a bit of work on your part to get the output into the required format (it just returns a single index).

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how compact was your solution? Also smart and compact might conflict each other. Smart would be (in a good data structure) a binary search. Compact would likely be around 5 lines of codes

Comment: Actually I need a fast solution. I have edited the question with the current solution I am using.

Comment: What approx size is the "very long interval" list? How long does it take right now?

Comment: The size of the interval list can be 10E5 at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (according to comments) you "need a fast solution", you are using the wrong output format. Using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) (or any other way of [binary-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)) you can find the right spot in O(logn), but if you want a list of `True`/`False` instead of a single integer value (the index of the interval) you will need O(n) just for constructing that list.

Thus, my suggestion is to use `bisect.bisect`. The result will be the position where the new element would have to be inserted in the list in order to remain in sorted order, i.e. `0` would be before the first interval (which according to your scenario can not happen) and `3` would be in the third interval.

```
>>> import bisect
>>> interval = [-5, -2, 0, 10]
>>> idx = bisect.bisect(interval, 1)
>>> idx
3
```

If you *really* need the list of `True` and `False`, you can still create it from that number in another step, but for most purposes the index value is probably more useful.

```
>>> [i == idx for i in range(1, len(interval))]
[False, False, True]
```

Update: A much faster way to generate the list, once you got the index with `bisect`, is:

```
res = [False] * (len(interval) - 1)
res[idx - 1] = True
```

Timing analysis using IPython's `%timeit`:

```
>>> n = 10000; k = 5000
>>> %timeit a = [i == k for i in range(1, n)]
450 µs ± 4.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit b = [False] * (n-1); b[k-1] = True
18.2 µs ± 24.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: The position si still ok, thank you so much. From there I can easily build the True/False list.

Comment: @crazydecibel Sure, you can do that, see the last part, just keep in mind that that _will_ mess up your performance. Finding the right interval in a list of 10,000 with bisect/binary-search might take as little as 15 steps, whereas creating that true/false list will take, well, 10,000 steps. And what's worse: Once you have that true/false list, you _again_ have to find the one element that's true (what else did you make it for?), and this time you can't even use binary search, just a linear scan, for another O(n) each time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?
It's hard to read.. but somewhat compact ^^

```
given_value = 1
interval = [-5, -2, 0, 10]

output = list(map(lambda x: (interval[x] < given_value < interval[x + 1]), range(len(interval) // 2 + 1)))
# output = [False, False, True]
```

Comment: Or: [interval[x] < value <= interval[x+1] for x in range(len(interval)-1)]

Comment: `len(interval) // 2 + 1` is wrong and just coincidentally works in this case. It should be `len(interval) - 1`